# Laravel search field

Tags: laravel

I have some issues with search field in my project. Hopefully someone can help me.
When I type what I want to search and press enter in url i just get

```
sitelink/?
```

instead of

```
sitelink/results?query=someting
```

Here are parts of code

All search logic is in web.php not in a seperate controller...

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/results', function(){
    $posts = \App\Post::where('title','like',  '%' . request('query') . '%')->get();

    return view('results')->with('posts', $posts)
        ->with('title', 'Search results : ' . request('query'))
        ->with('settings', \App\Setting::first())
        ->with('categories', \App\Category::take(6)->get())
        ->with('query', request('query'));
});
```

Here is **form**

```
<form method="GET" action="/results">
    <input class="overlay_search-input" name="query" placeholder="Type and hit Enter..." type="text">
    <a href="#" class="overlay_search-close">
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
    </a>
</form>
```

Also, when I type full url manualy for example

```
sitelink/results?query=find
```

It is working just fine but it does not send right url when I press enter on search field

Comment: Do you have any ```<input type="submit" value="Submit">``` somewhere? You need to have a button or something so you can submit your form, or work with JS to submit your form on key-up or anything.

Comment: use [url](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-url) helper for form action. your relative url is not working and thus you are redirected to a wrong url.

Comment: @ettdro it is going over js dont need button just should be able to press enter n that is it :)

Comment: @zahidhasanemon wont it be "hard coded" then ?

Comment: What does your JS look like?

Comment: no it won't. use like `<form method="GET" action="{{ url('/results') }}">`

Comment: still same @zahidhasanemon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in mistype in blade.php
I hope this will help someone.

Essentially, I had a form I header for search but I also had form in frontIndex.blade.php in one was edited form how it should be and in one it was not. So I created includes folder cutter form there and then included where I needed it. Now it is working just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are hitting your route ???
Try to get the query param in your function

```
Route::get('/results', function(){
    $query = Input::get('query');
    print_r($query);
    $posts = \App\Post::where('title','like',  '%' . $query . '%')->get();

});
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/str70n

 $query = request('query');
    dd($query);

That part of code u sent me seems like not working

Comment: it seems you are getting the query string then the problem is in you search query part

Comment: what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this one:

```
<form method="GET" action="action="{{ route('result') }}"">
  <input class="overlay_search-input" type="search" value="{{ isset($query) ? $query : '' }}"
 name="query" placeholder="Type and hit Enter..." type="text">
  <a href="#" class="overlay_search-close">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
   </a>
 </form>
```

web.php:
Route::get('/result','SearchController@search')->name('result');

Your controller should get the query input:

```
  $query = $request->input('query');
```